# Excel, Visual basic Loop

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a loop in Visual Basic, but i don´t know much about coding. I would really  appreciate a little bit of help, thanks :).
I´m trying to check if a currency price reaches certaint price, i have the prices in column A, and the historical prices in Column B, i need to check each cell of the column B until the historial price is bigger than The price in Column A +1 or the price in Column A -1, whatever happens first. if so return the name of the cell in column C and put an "x" in column D. Also, column A has 280 cell, so i have to check every value for every cell.

Is that possible to do?

[SAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G32zO.png)

Comment: Put some sample data. Also show some effort by you to solve the problem. Do you need `VBA`, if it can be done with formulas only?

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO ain't a place where you get others to do your work without showing what you've done so far. You should check [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to figure something out yourself before asking here. As @Harun24HR hinted at, this can be done with formulas only without need of code.

Comment: I´m sorry @T.Nesset. i´m new at this, in this link you can see some of the work i´ve done [link](https://imgur.com/a/iQhe5Rz) _italic_ **bold** `code`  i just don´t know hot to fill the last column i lack, it´s supposed to be done manually, but there are about 900 rows. i also uploaded a sample in the main question. Thanks :)

Comment: I have to check if the entry price reaches a certain price, which can be R1 or S1, that certain price could be a maximum or minimum, which are in High or Low column. i have to check after the entry price was publiched, so if the price is from 202-04-01 at 8.am, it needs to check after that hour, not before, and that can happen during the next 24 hours or even a day, so, the range is different in every case. I´m sorry if i didn´t explain it properly, it´s confusing

Comment: i assumed it can´t be done by formulas, but i can use them if they do the work @Harun24HR thanks too :)